# Retrieve values from a database and importing into table rows

Tags: php, html, mysql

Good day guys, I will be glad if you can help me out.
I have a project. and the remaining part of it is where i can pull out data from the database.
Its a tracking application. I want a situation whereby if a user type his/her reference number, it will display the results in a tabular from i.e
Reference Number, Ship date, ship weight, excpected delivery, ship country, ship state, city, zip, e.t.c. I have the following html code:

```
  <form id="track" name="track" method="post" action="tester.php"> 
        <h2>Track your shipment Here</h2>

      <p><label> Tracking Reference: 
      <input type="text" id="reference" name="reference" value="" maxlength="40" required="required" /></label></p>


      <div class="button_holder">

        <p>   <input type="submit" id="track" value="Track Now" maxlength="40" required="required" /></label>
      </label></p>

      </div>
```

and my php code is:

```
<?php

$ref = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reference']);

// conmnecting to the database
if(isset($ref)){ 
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'wisdom'); 
mysql_select_db('gday');

$query = "SELECT * FROM shipment WHERE id = '".$ref."' "; 
$row = mysql_query($query);


echo "<table border=\"1\"; width='550px'>"; // start a table tag in the HTML


//Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['ship_type'] . "</td><td>" . $row['ship_ref'] . "</td><td>" . $row['ship_date'] . "</td><td>" . $row['ship_weight'] . "</td><td>" . $row['expected_delivery'] . "</td></tr>" . $row['ship_country'] . "</td></tr>" . $row['ship_state'] . "</td></tr>" . $row['ship_city'] . "</td></tr>" . $row['ship_zip'] . "</td></tr>" . $row['remark'] . "</td></tr>";




echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection



}
else{echo " Enter a valid Reference Number";
exit;}


?>
```

Now, my major problem is this:  the following code output just the table without any information inserted, Please what could be done to make sure the rows are filled with data retrieved from the database?
Thanks

Comment: fetch fetch fetch.......................

Comment: This is PHP/Mysql 101. Very beginners stuff. You need to look up how the mysql functions work. And also, don't use them, they're deprecated and considered harmful.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, i agree and accept that its a beginner course, but how can you help me with that code? I will be so grateful

Answer (score 0):

**Fetch fetch fetch.......**

Change it like this:

```
$res= mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

`mysqli_` functions are deprecated, don't use them anymore. Use the MySQLi or PDO libraries instead.

Comment: I get an Undefined variables and mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\wamp\www\gday2\tester.php on line 11 error when i implemented the code. pls what is the correct usage? thanks

Comment: it didn't worked, reasons mat be `$ref` variable is empty or you dont have column `id`. try to see what is the query that is executing by `echo $query;` and you'll know what was wrong